# Coding style: assignments inside expressions?

Tags: c#, coding-style

Quick question asking for insight from this community: **Which one is preferable?**

---

### Option ①

```
// How many spaces are there in the beginning of string? (and remove them)
int spaces = text.Length;
text = text.TrimStart(' ');
spaces -= text.Length;
```

- **Advantage:** Assignment on a separate line, thus side-effect is explicit
- **Disadvantage:** The first line looks nonsensical by itself; you have to notice the third line to understand it

  ---

### Option ②

```
// How many spaces are there in the beginning of string? (and remove them)
int spaces = text.Length - (text = text.TrimStart(' ')).Length;
```

- **Advantage:** Statement makes sense in terms of the computation it performs
- **Disadvantage:** Assignment kinda hidden inside the expression; side-effect can be overlooked

---

Comment: Cute Unicode numbers.

Comment: I preffer the first code style, because second is hard to support

Comment: Assignments (mutations in general) in expressions are usually [always] wrong (but see `MoveNext`) -- that is, they make code less maintainable and harder to reason about. It is easy to look at the first example and go "I should use better names and avoid mutations to the `spaces` variable". The 2nd is just confusing -- there is too much going on that needs to be tracked mentally.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I don't like either of them. Some guidelines for writing clear code:

- The meaning of a variable should remain the same throughout the lifetime of the variable.

Option (1) violates this guideline; the variable "spaces" is commented as meaning "how many spaces are in text" but it at no time actually has this meaning!  It begins its lifetime by being the number of *characters* in text, and ends its lifetime as being the number of spaces that *used to be* in text. It means two different things throughout its lifetime and neither of them is what it is documented to mean.

- An expression statement has exactly one side effect. (An "expression statement" is a statement that consists of a single expression; in C# the legal statement expressions are method calls, object constructions, increments, decrements and assignments.)
- An expression has no side effects, except when the expression is the single side effect of an expression statement.

Option (2) obviously violates these guidelines. Expression statements that do multiple side effects are hard to reason about, they're hard to debug because you can't put the breakpoints where you want them, it's all bad.

I would rewrite your fragment to follow these guidelines.

```
string originalText = text;
string trimmedText = originalText.TrimStart(' ');
int removedSpaces = originalText.Length - trimmedText.Length;
text = trimmedText;
```

One side effect per line, and every variable means exactly the same thing throughout its entire lifetime.

Comment: Beautiful. Eric, I love learning from your code examples (I learned a lot from your integer rounding code). Not only you write beautiful code, you have an amazing ability to explain your programming philosophy.

Comment: Eric, I think you should start a 'Pimp My Code' style code reviews on your blog like how Wil Shipley did with Objective C [http://wilshipley.com/blog/2005/07/code-insults-mark-i.html]. May be even write a short e-book. I would gladly pay any money you charge for it.

Comment: +1 "The meaning of a variable should remain the same throughout the lifetime of the variable." Hear, hear!

Comment: actually one thing I frequently wonder is how cool it would be if the debugger could actually properly step through expressions, perhaps via a new "Step Into Expression" command...

Comment: @romkyns: As it stands now, you can "Step into specific" and pick a method in the expression in the submenu.

Answer (score 12):

I'd do option 1b:

```
int initial_length = text.Length;
text = text.TrimStart(' ');
int spaces = initial_length - text.Length;
```

Sure, it's almost a duplicate of option one, but it's a little clearer (and you might need the initial length of your string later on).

Comment: +1 Big yay to option 1b! The beauty is that the names of the variables document the calculation, always a good plan.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer option 1. Although option 2 is more concise, and works correctly, I think of the guy who has to maintain this after I've moved on and I want to make my code as understandable as possible. I may know that an assignment as an expression evaluates to the value assigned, but the next guy may not.

Answer (score 1):

What about an overload?

```
public static string TrimStart(this string s, char c, out int numCharsTrimmed) 
{
    numCharsTrimmed = s.Length;
    s = s.TrimStart(c);
    numCharsTrimmed -= s.Length;    
}
```

Comment: @pst -- how more so?  Doesn't it at least make it a one-time choice, rather than something to confront each time?

Answer (score 0):

Option ① All day.  It's readable.  Option ② is much more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score -3):

From the point of view of your question itself, I'd say not to do assignments within expressions because it's not supported in all languages, Python for example, so if you want to remain consistent in your own personal coding style, you could stick with the traditional assignments.

Comment: -1. User is clearly talking about C# code and looking for inputs. I don't think we need to bring in another programming language in to discussion.